# Error al ingresar datos a un objeto tipo interface c#

Tags: c#, interface

Tengo un ejercicio que en el tengo que crear una interface ***IAnimal*** y dos clases que utilizan esa interface **Dog** y **Cat**, pues en la interface tengo que crear *get set* llamado Name y un metodo que devuelva un string llamado SaySomething, la cuestion es que en el ejercicio tengo que crear en el Main un objeto tipo IAnimal y a traves de una combinacion de bucle y switch case tengo que ingresar datos a las dos clases **Dog** y **Cat** pero me da error de compilacion. Esta es una parte de de mi codigo del Main:

```
       IAnimal []animal=new  IAnimal [3];
        char ch;
        int i = 3;
        while (i != 0)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Its a dog or cat? (d/c)");
            ch = char.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("What its her name?");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How he does?");
            string voice = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 'd':

                         animal[i] = new Dog(name,voice);

                        break;

                case 'c':

                        animal[i] = new Cat(name,voice);
                        break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    continue;

            }
            i--;
        }
```

Comment: Puedes añadir las clases Cat y Dog. y Agregar que error te sale cuando ejecutas el codigo.

Comment: La idea de una interfaz, es que justamente sea una cascara para despues crear objetos de esa forma. Si tu interfaz animal dice voz, la voz del perro no va a ser igual a la del gato. Ahi es cuando vos decis que la clase perro es de tipo IAnimal, y la funcion voz, devuelve guau... la del gato devolvera miau.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

principalmente una Interfaz es solo un contrato que una clase debe cumplir, por lo tanto no se puede instanciar directamente. Otras clases pueden implementar sus propiedades y métodos.

Primero, debes crear tu interfaz:

```
interface IAnimales
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string SaySomething();
}
```

Luego, crear tu clase Cat y Dog implementando esa interfaz:

```
class Cat : IAnimales
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string SaySomething()
    {
        return "miauuuu";
    }
}
class Dog: IAnimales
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string SaySomething()
    {
        return "goauuu";
    }
}
```

Posteriormente, en el metodo Main haces la instanciación, dependiendo del tipo de animal con tu loop y switch, sería algo como esto:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            IAnimales objAnimal;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    objAnimal = new Cat { Name ="Kitty"};
                    Console.WriteLine($"My {objAnimal.Name} say {objAnimal.SaySomething()}");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    objAnimal = new Cat { Name="Puppy"};
                    Console.WriteLine($"My {objAnimal.Name} say {objAnimal.SaySomething()}");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

ojalá te sirva...

Answer (score -1):

Esta línea está mal:

```
IAnimal []animal=new  IAnimal [3];
```

debe ser:

```
IAnimal animal[] = new IAnimal[3];
```

o mejor aun:

```
var animal = new IAnimal[3];
```

Comment: ¿Este código no marcaría error?